# Получение данных с одного сайта на других

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Ребята, такой вопрос.

Есть головной сайт. Есть куча других сайтов.

Мне нужно информацию с головного сайта отображать на остальных.
Вопрос в том, в каком формате отдавать с головного, если количество других растет?
Т.е. сейчас на порядка 100 сайтов нужно выводить инфу.

**Отдаваемый контент**

-- Списки информации для админов. Может быть много, по этому нужно еще разбивать на несколько страниц.

-- Уведомления к некоторому функционалу. Например у дочернего сайта обновился определенный модуль и нужно вывести инфу об этом.

Каким образом такое лучше реализовывать?
Отдавать в xml формате? Что меньше всего будет грузить сервак головного сайта?

Comment: Весь отдаваемый контент можно сразу кэшировать, так же кэшировать на дочерних.
Если при получении с головного сайта придет определенный флаг, то обновлять кэш дочернего.

В принципе ничего сложного вроде нет. Юзать curl для лучше для получения с головного сайта?

Comment: @eicto, сделайте, пожалуйста, ваш комментарий ответом, я его выберу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделайте  json api, информацию требующую долгих запросов кэшируйте, сообщайте другим сайтам информацию о времени жизни данных, чтобы они хранили их у себя а не спрашивали у головного все время.

Answer (score -1):

100 сторонних сайтов это по сути как 100 одновременных людей сидящих на сайте, в любом случае если информация обменивается между скриптами, а не выводится в броузер - нагрузки практически нет никакой, поэтому спокойно можно деть данные для сторонних ресурсов в виде API интерфейса с JSON данными. По сути - будут отдаваться обычные текстовые файлы, размером не более чем хороший стилевой набор CSS правил, но без оных, так как графику и красивости включать явно не нужно для обмена информацией.
Даже если запросов будет 1000, или 5000 сильной разницы сайт не будет на себе ощущать. Размер выводимой информации сильно не влияет на работу скриптов.

Comment: > Даже если запросов будет 1000, или 5000 сильной разницы сайт не будет на себе ощущать. **Размер выводимой информации сильно не влияет на работу скриптов.**

нуну

Comment: >>>>Даже если запросов будет 1000, или 5000 сильной разницы сайт не будет на себе ощущать

Еще как будет. Отдельный сервак нужно будет под это дело ставить))